# Getting correlations from big mixed datasets with data.table

Tags: r, vector, correlation, numeric, categorical-data

I have a few big datasets for which I would like to get the correlations with one specific variable of that same dataset.

For example, the correlation of variable `A` with the other variables in the data.table.

1. Because of the size of the datasets I want to use data.table.
2. These datasets are not purely numerical, but also categorical.
3. I would therefore like to be able to apply different correlation methods dependent on the class of the variable. I would preferably use different correlations for categorical variables, i.e the spearman rank correlation.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
    "A   B   D  E  iso   year   
     1   A   1  NA ECU   2009   
     2   B   2  0  ECU   2009   
     3   D   3  0  BRA   2011   
     4   E   4  0  BRA   2011   
     5   D   7  NA ECU   2008   
     6   E   1  0  ECU   2008   
     7   A   3  2  BRA   2012   
     8   A   4  NA BRA   2012",
  header = TRUE
)
```

I get the numerical columns by using:

```
numcols <- which(sapply(df, is.numeric))
```

The next step for numerical variables should be something like:

```
dfcor <- df[, x := .(list(cor(.SD, use= "pairwise.complete.obs", method= "pearson"))), by = iso, .SDcols = numcols]
```

This however creates a column `x` with a vector of the correlations, instead of separate columns for the correlations:

```
c(1, 0.942908070944406, 0.365636212063565, NA, -0.970142500145332, 0.942908070944406, 1, 0.0509647191437626, NA, -0.845154254728517, 0.365636212063565, 0.0509647191437626, 1, NA, -0.502518907629606, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.970142500145332, -0.845154254728517, -0.502518907629606, NA, 1)
```

In addition, this answer only gives me the pearson correlations where applicable. I would however like use the spearman rank correlation as well. Any suggestions?